# On rowselect of a struts 2 jquery grid my rowselect values not coming correct

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

When i click on row of grid it is giving correct values (like cadio, 101) but i click on next
row it is giving values(like cadio, 101) which is wrong , the correct values will be (Biceps, 101). Explanation-  i am geeting row values like this:
cadio, 101
Biceps, 101

```
 <s:url id="exerDetailsGridUrl" action="exerDetailsGrid" />
 <sjg:grid id="exerDetailsGrid"
  href="%{exerDetailsGridUrl}"
  pager="false"
  gridModel="exList"
  formIds="FilterListForm"
  height="500"
  width="580"
  rowNum="10000"
  footerrow="true"
  onSelectRowTopics="getExInfoOnRowSelect"
  reloadTopics="reloadExerDetailsGrid"
    >
    <sjg:gridColumn name="exerId" index="exerId" title="Exercise Id" hidden="true" key="true" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="exGroupName" index="exGroupName" title="Group Name"   cssStyle="padding-left:100px" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="exerName" index="exerName" title="Exercise Name"   />
  </sjg:grid>
```

Row Select Event

```
      $.subscribe('getExInfoOnRowSelect', function(event, data) {
            $("#exerId").val(event.originalEvent.id);
            alert(event.originalEvent.id);
            var grid = event.originalEvent.grid;
            var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'exGroupName');
            alert(myCellData); //THIS PRINTS THE VALUE i NEED!!!

        });
```

Comment: Got solution - remove key="true" then all working fine.